# extract values of their type from result_array()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to be able to take values from a result_array() query to use in another query.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [taskID] => 10 )
  [1] => Array ( [taskID] => 11 )
  [2] => Array ( [taskID] => 12 )
)
```

I want to be able to loop through each of the items in the array and return the value (e.g. 10, 11, 12) to be used in a where clause.

`$task` being the array and `$t` being the items in the array.

```
foreach($task as $t){
    $this->db->select('roleID');
    $this->db->from('project_tasks');
    $this->db->where('taskID', $t); //ERROR line 287
}
```

**ERROR:**

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `roleID` FROM `project_roles` WHERE `taskID` = `Array`
>
> Filename: models/Project_model.php
>
> Line Number: 287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting that `$task` is an array of arrays:

```
foreach($task as $t){
    $this->db->select('roleID');
    $this->db->from('project_tasks');
    $this->db->where('taskID', $t['taskID']); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$t[0]['taskID']` and would that give the desired behavior?

Comment: @Xorifelse Nope. `$t` is an element of `$task`.

Comment: well after your edit it makes a little more sense. I was expecting that the array was a dump from inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($task as $t){
    $this->db->select('roleID');
    $this->db->from('project_tasks');
    $this->db->where('taskID', $t['taskID']);
}
```